# Download Data from http request then add to table view like app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

How can I take data I've downloaded from a http connection then add the data to the table view in chunks like the apps store so if you scroll to the bottom it says load 25 more.
 [image: Screenshot of what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your back-end service supports a "retrieve the next 25" function of some sort, I think doing this would require you to implement a custom table cell that is returned when your table data model is asked for the cell in the last row. When selected, your table delegate would then need to request the next 25 results and update the contents of the table's data provider with the results.